# What is the best punctuation mark to use before a list of adverbs?

Tags: punctuation

In the essay I'm doing, I'm trying to conclude with the sentence

> As we can see, nuclear power is the most viable source of energy, economically, socially, morally and environmentally.

However, I'm not sure about what punctuation mark I should be using after the word "energy". The comma looks awkward, but I don't know of a more appropriate/natural punctuation mark.

Comment: If you want to keep the adverbs rather than use phrases like "from a ... point of view/perspective", I'd suggest using em dashes: "As we can see nuclear power is -- economically, socially, morally and sustainably -- the most viable source of energy." (By the way, wouldn't "environmentally" be more suitable than "sustainably"? We don't tend to find "sustainably" as an independent, isolated adverb, do we?)

Comment: @Gustavson I take your point about "sustainably", but in my question's current form, what is the best punctuation mark to use?

Comment: Yes, an m-dash would go well there.

Answer (score 1):

No punctuation would be best.

'As we can see, nuclear power is the most viable source of energy economically, socially, morally and environmentally' is perfectly fine with no punctuation after 'energy'